# how can I run some code before all $http call in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to check if user is `online` before making call using `$http` in angular app, as a fallback I will get the `cached data` if network is not available.

Is there any option like `before` callback in `$http` do run this check?

Or maybe any other way to tackle this, I have `network state` & cache in `localstorage`

Comment: You can add [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)

Comment: ok, so no option on $http library I guess, I have to do it in interceptor, it has then, catch and finally, no before callback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just write your own http service wrapper.

```
function httpMonkey ($http) { // I like to call all my services 'monkeys'; I find it makes angular more fun
  function request (args) {
    // stuff to do before, likely as a promise
    .then(function () {
      // the actual http request using $http
    })
    .then(function () {
      // stuff to do after, perhaps?
    });
  }

  var service = { request: request };
  return service;
}

angular
  .module('example')
  .factory('HttpMonkey', httpMonkey);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a custom **httpInteceptor** to the **$httpProvider** service in angularJs. 
As an example below - I have created an httpInteceptor which will show loadingSpinner before each $http call and hide it after success/error.

```
//Intercepts ALL angular ajax http calls
app.factory('httpInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope, $log) {
    var numLoadings = 0;
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            numLoadings++;
            // Show loader
            $('#loadingSpinner').show();
            return config || $q.when(config)
        },
        response: function (response) {
            if ((--numLoadings) === 0) {
                // Hide loader
                $('#loadingSpinner').hide();
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (response) {
            if (!(--numLoadings)) {
                // Hide loader
                $('#loadingSpinner').hide();
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
})
```

and then push this interceptor to the $httpProvider.interceptors in your app.config-

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
      .
      .

});
```